# I am trying to run an if else function when two variables equal each other

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a program where it asks for 2 names, and if they are the same they run an if function. However I can't make this work. I have this so far:

```py
Vote = input("Judge 1 vote: ")
Vote_1 = input("Judge 2 vote: ")

if Vote == Vote_1
    print("Announce the winner.")
else
    print("Ask for a third judge.")
```

`if Vote == Vote_1` is my problem area. I can't get it to work. Please help me.

Comment: You should elaborate more on what is not working. We can't understand your real problem by just a 'I can't get it to work' sentence. Here is just my assumption, but do you means it will always go to the else block? If yes, have you try to print the value and see?

Comment: In general it is helpful if you include the traceback / error message you received.

Comment: Kindly put the semicolons after the if and else statements.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the colons `:` in the `if` and `else` lines.

```py
vote_1 = input("Judge 1 vote: ")
vote_2 = input("Judge 2 vote: ")

if vote_1 == vote_2:
    print("Announce the winner.")
else:
    print("Ask for a third judge.")
```

## TIPS

1. Variable names (and function names) in Python follow the `snake_case`, `CamelCase` is reserved for class names.
2. `input` reads the data from the console as a string, if you want to compare it properly you should probably cast them to integers or floats.
3. Variable names should be descriptive, if you have two votes, `vote` for the first and `vote_1` for the second is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax errror on line that `if vote == vote_1`. Please try the following.

```
vote = input("Judge 1 vote: ");
vote_1 = input("Judge 2 vote: ");

if vote == vote_1:
    print("Announce the winner")
else:
    print("Ask for a third judge")
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all you have take an input and give it to a variable like this:

```
1st_person = input("judge 1 vote")
2nd_person = input("Judge 2 vote")
```

Now you can run any statement on both these variable for example:

```
if 1st_person == 2nd_person:
   print("Third judge is required!")
else:
   print("Announce the winner!")
```

I dont knwo what you are trying to achieve with this program, because it doesn't make any sense to caompare two names and then announce a winner but still i made it for you, but in case if your question is not clear ask me a question

Comment: Variable names in Python can't start by numbers